# DecimalField validation error, returns incorrect value Django

Tags: django, decimal

Ive got a DecimalField in one of my forms where a user enters a price.

Say the user enters 11.00, now when i retrieve it as in (priceform.cleaned_data) it returns

```
Decimal('11.00')
```

so it looks like

```
price = Decimal('11.00')
```

which triggers a validation error when i try to insert it into the database.

I'm coming up blank to any solutions for this

**models.py**

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class BidForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ['price']
```

**views.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
      bidform = BidForm(request.POST)
      if bidform.is_valid():
            price = bidform.cleaned_data['price']
            bid = Bid.objects.create(title=title, price=bidform, user=username)
            bid.save()
```

Comment: In your DecimalField,  increase decimal_places=2, make it 3 or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `price` should be the `price`, not `bidform`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    bidform = BidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if bidform.is_valid():
        bid = Bid.objects.create(
            title=title,
            price=bidform.cleaned_data['price'],
            user=username
        )
```

You can however let the form do the work:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    bid = Bid(
        title=title,
        user=username
    )
    bidform = BidForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=bid)
    if bidform.is_valid():
        bid = bidform.save()
```